# php curl redirect to another website with specific url format

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

Hey so i'm trying to link my current subdomain to new domain with specific url format.

Example my current subdomain is:

http://current.example.org/

what i would like to do is at the event of specific url format redirect to new domain:

http://newexample.org/url?=http://current.example.org/somefolder

any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer per comment (you may need to do some tweaking, I'm not sure of the exact value of `_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "somefolder") !== false){
    // redirect
    header('Location: http://newexample.org/url?='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Original answer follows:

If the url contains `'somefolder'` then append to redirect url, you mean?

```
$url = 'http://current.example.org/somefolder' ;
if (FALSE !== strpos($url, 'somefolder')) {
     $url = 'http://newexample.org/url?=.'$url ;
}
// curl connect using $url
```

Comment: First of all thanks for helping and yes if it the url contains specific folder it will redirect to new domain's folder. So let's say i have folder  on http://current.example.org/myfolder and then i can access to from new domain by simply using http://newexample.org/url?=http://current.example.org/myfolder

Comment: This is confusing.  Do you want your client (curl) to recognize `'myfolder'` and use the new domain, or do you want your server to redirect to the old domain when it gets a query string with an url in it?  Server redirects aren't a curl thing, really.

Comment: sorry for confusion. So i have 'somefolder" located on bother servers but i would like to use new server for downloading. Example:http://current.example.org/somefolder so when user visits that page i would like to redirect to http://newexample.org/url?=http://current.example.org/myfolder

Comment: I've update my answer to show basically how to do a conditional redirect from the server end.  Note that curl is not involved.